# Bind IsChecked to bitfield

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, bit-manipulation, ivalueconverter

I have a bitfield like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum EmployeeType
{
    None = 0,
    IsInOffice = 1,
    IsManager = 2,
    IsOnVacation = 4,
    ...
}
```

My UI has a listbox of all employees and I want to implement checkboxes to filter the list. This listbox is bound to a filter property like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> FilteredEmployees
    => _employees.Where(e => _regexFilter.IsMatch(e.FullName)
                                && (!EmployeeType.HasFlag(EmployeeType.IsInOffice) || e.IsLoggedIn)
                                && (!EmployeeType.HasFlag(EmployeeType.IsManager) || e.RoleID >= 4)
                                && (!EmployeeType.HasFlag(EmployeeType.IsOnVacation) || TimeRec.GetStatusID(e.ID) == 7))
                 .OrderBy(e => e.FullName);
```

My problem now is that I can't get a correct return value from the converter, since the current state of all flags is not known there and I also can't manage to get the current state of all flags into the converter.

I'm able to activate a flag but I'm unable to deactivate any flag without deactivating or activating others, which would be unintended behavior.

Comment: I think there is an error in `!EmployeeType.HasFlag(EmployeeType.IsInOffice)`. It might be `!e.EmployeeType.HasFlag(EmployeeType.IsInOffice)` instead.

Comment: EmployeeType is a property in my ViewModel which gets set when selecting an employee. The employee object itself has no idea what type it is. I'm the 'new guy' and I have no clue why there's no db column for that :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I got it using this:

Converter:

```
if ((bool)value)
    return (EmployeeType)parameter;
else
    return ~(EmployeeType)parameter;
```

Setter:

```
if ((int)value > 0)
    _employeeType |= value;
else
    _employeeType &= value;
```

Not 100% sure if it's a hack that just works in my scenario but well, it works :D